# OOM Error due to too many Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

I am using `GridView` with some bitmaps.
If I press the (hardware) back-button and restart the activity, new memory gets allocated. If I do it more often and with bigger bitmaps I get OOM very fast.

Using `DDMS` and tracking shows me the instances of all the `BitmapFactory.`

In my Manifest file I use 
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
for my activity but the problem still persists.

Even if i call the intent with

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
or
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`
it always creates new activities.

How can i make sure that going to that activity will reopen the old activity or how can i make sure that it gets destroyed and the memory freed once it isn't in the foreground anymore?

Comment: When you press back, the Activity is destroyed and all its non-static references are freed. Make sure you don't keep static fields around, a static reference to a Context is the first cause of memory leaks.
To help you more you would need to show some code.

Comment: I can tell you right now: this issue has nothing to do with `Intents`. You just have a memory leak somewhere. Are you keeping any static references anywhere in your app? Do you perform tasks in the background with `AsyncTasks` or something similar? Most memory leaks are caused by improper usage of either the static keyword or `AsyncTasks`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. than i try to find a leak in Async!